# Too wide ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, horizontalscrollview

I want to display an ImageView on some Layout, but I can't do it in the correct way. My image is very wide and I want to stretch its height to the screen, but the width shouldn't stretch the screen's width. My ImageView (actually class extending an ImageView) is intelligent so I can move it by dragging. I don't want to use HorizontalScrollView, because when I drag the image, onDrag events are intercepted by the parent (HorizontalScrollView), not by my ImageView.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        

        <pl.tripassistant.util.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/snoop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout

Comment: i posted it now in first post